# Kendo Grid for Angular 4/5 Bind Blur Event to Row/Grid

Tags: angular, for-loop, kendo-ui, grid

I have tried this implementation using Jquery with some modifications:

```
$('kendo-grid').on('blur', 'tr.k-state-selected', function(e) {
    this.closeEditor(this.grid, this.editedRowIndex);
})
```

and nothing seems to work so I'm wondering if it's even possible to attach a blur event to the overall grid or if I need to do it via column events or something else. Any advice would be appreciated.